# apxs error: gcc: no suchf file or directory

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, gentoo

i am trying to install mod_xsendfile to my gentoo server.

I did:

```
cd /usr/local/apache/bin
./apxs -cia /mod_xsendfile.c
```

and doenst' work.

it says:

```
gcc: /mod_sendfile.c: No such file or directory
```

but the file is there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small chance that the file is located at `/mod_xsendfile.c`, it does not belong there. You possibly meant the current directory, either remove the slash, or replace the slash by `./` (current directory):

```
cd /usr/local/apache/bin
./apxs -cia mod_xsendfile.c
```